# Calculate Balance by one column with different types (another column), same table

Tags: mysql, sql

here is the table which Im use to save transactions by accounts:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| Field      | Type                |
+------------+---------------------+
| id         | int(11)             | 
| account_id | int(11)             | 
| type       | tinyint(4)          |
| currency   | tinyint(3) unsigned | 
| amount     | decimal(16,8)       | 
| created_at | timestamp           | 
+------------+---------------------+
```

Transactions Example:

```
+----+------------+------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | account_id | type | currency | amount      | created_at          |
+----+------------+------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 |          1 |    1 |        1 | 10.00000000 | 2020-01-30 16:44:43 |
|  2 |          1 |    2 |        1 |  6.00000000 | 2020-01-31 12:20:58 |
+----+------------+------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Tell me please, how I can SELECT difference between SUM(amount) with type 1 and SUM(amount) with type 2 FROM the same table.

Result should be : 4.00000000 (10.00000000 - 6.00000000) with provided data in example.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. (Perhaps some more sample data is needed to illustrate the problem.)

Comment: Only result 4.00000000, for the whole table? One single row? One column?

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses after and int or tinyint declaration is almost meaningless, and probably best omitted

Comment: @jarlh

Yes, the answer already provided below

Comment: `select sum(case type when 1 then amount when 2 then -amount end) from transactions`

Comment: @jairth Hard solution )

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you want the sums per account_id, so use conditional aggregation:

```
select account_id,
  sum(case when type = 1 then amount else 0 end) -
  sum(case when type = 2 then amount else 0 end) result
from transactions
group by account_id
```

If you want the difference for the whole table then remove `group by`:

```
select 
  sum(case when type = 1 then amount else 0 end) -
  sum(case when type = 2 then amount else 0 end) result
from transactions
```

Since you tagged **MySql**, the difference can be simplified to this:

```
sum(((type = 1) - (type = 2)) * amount)
```

Comment: @NikolayShen if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple aggregation with `sum()`:

```
select t.account_id, 
       sum(case when type = 1 then t.amount 
                when type = 2 then - t.amount 
                else 0 
           end) as Result 
from transactions t
group by t.account_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simply `DIFFERENCE`:

```
select account_id, DIFFERENCE(select sum(amount) where type=1,select sum(amount) where type=0)as Result where transactions
```

Comment: I have never seen this syntax.  In what database would this work?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sql

Comment: . . I am quite familiar with SQL.  I have never seen this syntax.